# Can theorem provers be used to form foundations for programming languages?

Tags: design, programming-languages

I started programming a Haskell-clone recently ([source code](https://github.com/cheery/flog)).

After basic hindley-milner, problems start to arise. Implementation of data/codata statements seem to ensure my language is breaking up on every front.

At this point I seem to lack foundations for the language. System F introduces kinds, but would it be better to approach theorem provers and pick a different calculus as foundation?

Also looking for overall suggestions for this kind of a project.

Comment: Are you using "theorem provers" and "proof assistants" as synonyms?

Comment: Yes. I meant proof assistants.

Answer (score 12):

If you are asking "can we use proof assistants to develop foundations of programming languages" then the answer is positive. Two well-known such developments are:

- [Software foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu) by Benjamin Pierce, implemented in Coq.
- [Programming language foundations in Agda](https://plfa.github.io) by Phil Wadler, implemented in Agda.

There are also specialized proof assistants that make it easier to develop the meta-theory of a programming language, such as [Twelf](http://twelf.org/wiki/Main_Page), [Abella](http://abella-prover.org) and [Beluga](http://complogic.cs.mcgill.ca/beluga/).

Comment: edits should be at least 6 characters. weird...

Comment: Fixed, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I'm interested in this application of theorem provers, but it's not my speciality. I can point you to Harper and Licata's paper [Mechanizing Metatheory in a Logical Framework](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Erwh/papers/mech/jfp07.pdf), which walks through using [Twelf](http://twelf.org/wiki/Main_Page) to prove results about a toy functional programming language.